# How to change font size for specific lstlisting

Tags: listings

I have a java lstlisting and it is too big and does not mach a single page.

Is there any way to specify font for specific listing, not all listings in document?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can set the option directly with the `lstlisting` environment option `basicstyle`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    basicstyle=\tiny, %or \small or \footnotesize etc.
]
int isJava = 1;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122916/32374)

Comment: I really like this approach, but one needs to remember that other attributes of `basicstyle` (such as the font colour), will be lost when the size is changed this way.

Comment: Actually, the colours seem to stay the same, but one needs to specify `\ttfamily` as well so as not to lose monospace font.

Comment: This really isn't a good solution, as it breaks carefully designed styles. As some others comment here, one can adjust things locally as well, but this is brittle for large documents.  If you change the global style later, you might not remember to make fixes for the customized listing.  There is hopefully a better way ...

Answer (score 31):

The best way to do this is by using the `lstdefinestyle` functionality which is built into the listings package.  Encapsulate your style as follows (I've used a crummy MATLAB style definition as an example):

```
\lstdefinestyle{myCustomMatlabStyle}{
  language=Matlab,
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=10pt,
  tabsize=4,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false
}
```

Then, use it like so:

```
% A "large" listing
\lstset{basicstyle=\large,style=myCustomMatlabStyle}

\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}

% A "tiny" listing
\lstset{basicstyle=\tiny,style=myCustomMatlabStyle}

\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

The results of the two different `lstlisting`'s will be different sizes, as set by your `basicstyle` command.

If you do not want to set the style globally with `\lstset`, you can also set the style only for a specific `lstlisting`:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myCustomMatlabStyle]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

or even set all properties in the `lstlisting`, without defining a style:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab,
                   numbers=left,
                   stepnumber=1,
                   numbersep=10pt,
                   tabsize=4,
                   showspaces=false,
                   showstringspaces=false]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Be careful with `\lstset`, though; its effects are global.