# LaTeX source code listing like in professional books for \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings

Found this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books and I'm very satisfied with this soulution, it looks just great in a generated pdf file. But how can I do the same for source code that I insert to my *.tex file with `\lstinputlisting`? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: that is already shown in the example.

Comment: @Herbert: thank you so much! I don't know why I haven't noticed it before :) Now it's all clear. Cheers!

Comment: You can also upvote [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63962/19356).