# How to show similar display of codes of different programming languages in LaTeX

Tags: listings, code, wolfram-mathematica

I am very new to LaTeX and I am writing my thesis. In a chapter, I want to show my codes, which are in Mathematica.
[image]

I use the `listings` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{listings}  
\begin{document}  
\lstset{language=Mathematica}  

\begin{lstlisting}  
Do[i^j,{i,1,10},{j,1,10}]  
\end{lstlisting}  

\end{document}
```

However, the output is much different to what the code looks like in the Mathematica IDE (even if I use other languages in `\lstset{language=<name>}`):

[image]

I read some questions on the site but, in some of them, the font or color of the codes were not the same. Could you please help me to display something like the picture below in LaTeX?

If it is important, I am using the BiDi package.

Comment: As I said in my previously deleted answer, perhaps https://github.com/gpoore/minted can be useful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Taken partially from my old answer [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63962/19356).

This code should not be considered as a bombastic template but an easy-to-customize one.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,border=15pt,preview,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\null,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=5,
    columns=flexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    captionpos=b,% or t for top (default)
    abovecaptionskip=0.5\smallskipamount,   % there is also belowcaptionskip
}

\lstdefinestyle{DOS}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Black},
    basicstyle=\color{White}\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
}


\lstdefinestyle{Mathematica}
{
    style=Common,
    language={Mathematica},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        Animate,
        AnimationRunning,
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{Fortran}
{
    style=Common,
    language={Fortran},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        % add your new fortran keywords here!
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{CSharp}
{
    style=Common,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
    morekeywords=
    {
        % add your new fortran keywords here!
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{CSFall}
{
    style=CSharp,   
    backgroundcolor=\color{Blue},
    basicstyle=\color{Yellow}\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{White}\sffamily,
    identifierstyle=\color{Cyan}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
    stringstyle=\color{Maroon},
    numberstyle=\color{Black}\tiny\noaccsupp,
    rulecolor=\color{Black},
}


\lstdefinestyle{MathWinter}
{
    style=Mathematica,
    keywordstyle=\color{Maroon},
    identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    backgroundcolor=\color{Orange!10},
    numberstyle=\color{Red}\tiny\noaccsupp,
    rulecolor=\color{Red},
}

\lstdefinestyle{MathSummer}
{
    style=Mathematica,
    keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
    identifierstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
    backgroundcolor=\color{Cyan!10},
    numberstyle=\color{Black}\tiny\noaccsupp,
    rulecolor=\color{Maroon},
}


\lstdefinestyle{ForSpring}
{
    style=Fortran,
    keywordstyle=\color{Magenta},
    identifierstyle=\color{Red},
    backgroundcolor=\color{ForestGreen!10},
    numberstyle=\color{NavyBlue}\tiny\noaccsupp,
    rulecolor=\color{NavyBlue},
}

\lstnewenvironment{CSFall}
{\lstset{style=CSFall}}
{}


\lstnewenvironment{MathWinter}
{\lstset{style=MathWinter}}
{}

\lstnewenvironment{MathSummer}
{\lstset{style=MathSummer}}
{}

\lstnewenvironment{ForSpring}[1][]
{\lstset{style=ForSpring,#1}}
{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fortran.f95}
FORMAT("EXTERNAL CODE")
INTEGER A,B,C
READ(5,501,END=50,ERR=90) A,B,C
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{CSFall}
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PSTricks is better than TikZ.");// single-line comment
    }
    /* multi-line comment */
}
\end{CSFall}


\begin{MathWinter}
Do[i^j, {i,1,10}, {j,1,10}];
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}, AnimationRunning -> False] 
\end{MathWinter}

\begin{MathSummer}
Do[i^j, {i,1,10}, {j,1,10}];
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}, AnimationRunning -> False] 
\end{MathSummer}

\begin{ForSpring}[caption={An example of Fortran code.}]
FORMAT("INLINE CODE")
INTEGER A,B,C
READ(5,501,END=50,ERR=90) A,B,C
\end{ForSpring}

\lstinputlisting[style=ForSpring,caption={An example of Fortran code.}]{fortran.f95}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=DOS]
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\Users\Garbage Collector>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you decrease the width of a code block in listing? For instance, instead of a page width code block, we have a half-page code block.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: use `linewidth=.25\linewidth` for example.