# Including both XML code and Java code in a document using lstlisting package

Tags: listings, packages, xml, java

I am writing a document which has both `java` and `xml` codes, I managed to highlight my `java` code but unfortunately I was unable to do the same with `xml`, so far I have tried more than one way either by including the style set or by modifying the `lstlisting`  file and add key words, I dont know what is the issue exactly my `xml` code still not highlighted !!!!
I appreciate any support Thanks in advance !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193475/19356

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't supplied a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it is not clear what you have tried, but doesn't specifying the `language` for each listing environment do what you want? For example, you can highlight the following java and xml code snippets like this

[image]

by typing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,color}
\begin{document}

\lstloadlanguages{javascript,xml}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=java]
  public class HelloWorld
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml]
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <addresses>
    <address>
      <name>Joe Tester</name>
      <street>Baker street 5</street>
    </address>
  </addresses>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```