# How to set up listings for use code from Arduino?

Tags: listings, color, code

Well, I'm creating notes from a course of Arduino in LaTeX and I was reading about the `listings`package and I want to use it with the code of the exercises of the course. I know Arduino uses a language based on Processing that isn't included yet in the languages that `listings` can recognize.

So, my question is if there is a way to configure or set up `listings` for create blocks of code for Arduino and can use typographical or color schemes for distinguish comments, variables, definitions, etc.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{listings}    

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.47,0.47,0.33}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{0.8,0.4,0}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.01,0.61,0.98}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{mywhite},   
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                   
  commentstyle=\color{mygray},    
  deletekeywords={...},           
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=shadowbox,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  keywordstyle=\color{myorange},       
  language=Octave,                
  morekeywords={*,...},            
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, 
  rulecolor=\color{black},         
  rulesepcolor=\color{myblue},
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=2,                    
  stringstyle=\color{myorange},    
  tabsize=2,                       
  title=\lstname                   
}    

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Arduino UNO diagram.}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{First programs}

\minisec{Sketch 1: A flashing LED on a protoboard}

\begin{lstlisting}
 /*  
 Sketch un led intermitente en una tarjeta de pruebas. 
 Es practicamente lo mismo que un Hello World.
 En este caso cambiamos el pin del LED y usamos un LED externo, ademas del LED hay que colocar un resistor entre el LED y tierra. 
 */

void setup(){
  //inicializa el pin digital 9 como salida (output)
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH); //pone el LED en HIGH (encendido)
  delay(1000); // espera por un segundo, 1000 ms
  digitalWrite(9,LOW); // pone el LED en LOW (apagado)
  delay(1000); // espera por un segundo, 1000 ms
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I get a nice frame with a color shadow, but I want to get also color inside the code.

Comment: If you don't mind, please see my answer several decades ago [here (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193475/19356).

Comment: @Whoiscrazyfirst several centuries ago ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to provide the definitions for the language:

[image]

You can tweak many things, but to illustrate the changes I made are:

- comments (both the `/* ... */` and the single line `//` are in red,
- keywords are highligted in `myorange`,
- identifiers (manually specified) are highlighted in bold blue
- numbers (not in comments) are highlighted in green. If you want the numbers in the commens highlighted as well remove the `*` in `literate=*`.

### References:

- [Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{listings}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}    

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.47,0.47,0.33}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{0.8,0.4,0}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.01,0.61,0.98}

\newcommand*{\FormatDigit}[1]{\ttfamily\textcolor{mygreen}{#1}}
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers
\lstdefinestyle{FormattedNumber}{%
    literate=*{0}{{\FormatDigit{0}}}{1}%
             {1}{{\FormatDigit{1}}}{1}%
             {2}{{\FormatDigit{2}}}{1}%
             {3}{{\FormatDigit{3}}}{1}%
             {4}{{\FormatDigit{4}}}{1}%
             {5}{{\FormatDigit{5}}}{1}%
             {6}{{\FormatDigit{6}}}{1}%
             {7}{{\FormatDigit{7}}}{1}%
             {8}{{\FormatDigit{8}}}{1}%
             {9}{{\FormatDigit{9}}}{1}%
             {.0}{{\FormatDigit{.0}}}{2}% Following is to ensure that only periods
             {.1}{{\FormatDigit{.1}}}{2}% followed by a digit are changed.
             {.2}{{\FormatDigit{.2}}}{2}%
             {.3}{{\FormatDigit{.3}}}{2}%
             {.4}{{\FormatDigit{.4}}}{2}%
             {.5}{{\FormatDigit{.5}}}{2}%
             {.6}{{\FormatDigit{.6}}}{2}%
             {.7}{{\FormatDigit{.7}}}{2}%
             {.8}{{\FormatDigit{.8}}}{2}%
             {.9}{{\FormatDigit{.9}}}{2}%
             %{,}{{\FormatDigit{,}}{1}% depends if you want the "," in color
             {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
             ,%
}


\lstset{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{mywhite},   
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                   
  commentstyle=\color{red},    
  deletekeywords={...},           
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=shadowbox,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  keywordstyle=\color{myorange},       
  language=Octave,                
  morekeywords={*,...},            
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, 
  rulecolor=\color{black},         
  rulesepcolor=\color{myblue},
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=2,                    
  stringstyle=\color{myorange},    
  tabsize=2,                       
  title=\lstname,
  emphstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},%  style for emph={} 
}    

%% language specific settings:
\lstdefinestyle{Arduino}{%
    style=FormattedNumber,
    keywords={void},%                 define keywords
    morecomment=[l]{//},%             treat // as comments
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},%         define /* ... */ comments
    emph={HIGH, OUTPUT, LOW},%        keywords to emphasize
}

\newtoggle{InString}{}% Keep track of if we are within a string
\togglefalse{InString}% Assume not initally in string

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Arduino UNO diagram.}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{First programs}

\minisec{Sketch 1: A flashing LED on a protoboard}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Arduino]
 /*  
 Sketch un led intermitente en una tarjeta de pruebas. 
 Es practicamente lo mismo que un Hello World.
 En este caso cambiamos el pin del LED y usamos un LED externo, ademas del LED hay que colocar un resistor entre el LED y tierra. 
 */

void setup(){
  //inicializa el pin digital 9 como salida (output)
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH); //pone el LED en HIGH (encendido)
  delay(1000); // espera por un segundo, 1000 ms
  digitalWrite(9,LOW); // pone el LED en LOW (apagado)
  delay(1000); // espera por un segundo, 1000 ms
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, two doubt, I see how to emphasize few words, such as `HIGH` or `LOW` but how to do it with number? If I use the `morekeywords` option for add keywords but I want a different color, could I achieve that?

Comment: @Aradnix: See revised solution that will highlight numbers as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/trihedral/AdruinoLatexListing)'s a listing saved to an external file that adds Arduino as a language, and highlights all the builtin types and functions properly.

---

Place `arduinoLanguage.tex` file in your working directory (next to the LaTeX file you're working on). To add it to your project, place:

```
\input{arduinoLanguage.tex}
```

somewhere before `\begin{document}` in your LaTeX file.

In your document, place your Arduino code between:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Arduino]
%% arduino code here %%
\end{lstlisting}
```

Or create your own style to make changes like adding non-built-in functions and variables:

```
\lstdefinestyle{myArduino}{
  language=Arduino,
%% make listing changes here %%
}
```

And place your Arduino code between:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myArduino]
%% arduino code here %%
\end{lstlisting}
```

#### `arduinoLanguage.tex`

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%%% ~ Arduino Language - Arduino IDE Colors ~                                  %%%
%%%                                                                            %%%
%%% Kyle Rocha-Brownell | 10/2/2017 | No Licence                               %%%
%%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------- %%%
%%%                                                                            %%%
%%% Place this file in your working directory (next to the latex file you're   %%%
%%% working on).  To add it to your project, place:                            %%%
%%%    \input{arduinoLanguage.tex}                                             %%%
%%% somewhere before \begin{document} in your latex file.                      %%%
%%%                                                                            %%%
%%% In your document, place your arduino code between:                         %%%
%%%   \begin{lstlisting}[language=Arduino]                                     %%%
%%% and:                                                                       %%%
%%%   \end{lstlisting}                                                         %%%
%%%                                                                            %%%
%%% Or create your own style to add non-built-in functions and variables.      %%%
%%%                                                                            %%%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}    
\usepackage{courier}

%%% Define Custom IDE Colors %%%
\definecolor{arduinoGreen}    {rgb} {0.17, 0.43, 0.01}
\definecolor{arduinoGrey}     {rgb} {0.47, 0.47, 0.33}
\definecolor{arduinoOrange}   {rgb} {0.8 , 0.4 , 0   }
\definecolor{arduinoBlue}     {rgb} {0.01, 0.61, 0.98}
\definecolor{arduinoDarkBlue} {rgb} {0.0 , 0.2 , 0.5 }

%%% Define Arduino Language %%%
\lstdefinelanguage{Arduino}{
  language=C++, % begin with default C++ settings 
%
%
  %%% Keyword Color Group 1 %%%  (called KEYWORD3 by arduino)
  keywordstyle=\color{arduinoGreen},   
  deletekeywords={  % remove all arduino keywords that might be in c++
                break, case, override, final, continue, default, do, else, for, 
                if, return, goto, switch, throw, try, while, setup, loop, export, 
                not, or, and, xor, include, define, elif, else, error, if, ifdef, 
                ifndef, pragma, warning,
                HIGH, LOW, INPUT, INPUT_PULLUP, OUTPUT, DEC, BIN, HEX, OCT, PI, 
                HALF_PI, TWO_PI, LSBFIRST, MSBFIRST, CHANGE, FALLING, RISING, 
                DEFAULT, EXTERNAL, INTERNAL, INTERNAL1V1, INTERNAL2V56, LED_BUILTIN, 
                LED_BUILTIN_RX, LED_BUILTIN_TX, DIGITAL_MESSAGE, FIRMATA_STRING, 
                ANALOG_MESSAGE, REPORT_DIGITAL, REPORT_ANALOG, SET_PIN_MODE, 
                SYSTEM_RESET, SYSEX_START, auto, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, 
                uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, char16_t, char32_t, operator, 
                enum, delete, bool, boolean, byte, char, const, false, float, double, 
                null, NULL, int, long, new, private, protected, public, short, 
                signed, static, volatile, String, void, true, unsigned, word, array, 
                sizeof, dynamic_cast, typedef, const_cast, struct, static_cast, union, 
                friend, extern, class, reinterpret_cast, register, explicit, inline, 
                _Bool, complex, _Complex, _Imaginary, atomic_bool, atomic_char, 
                atomic_schar, atomic_uchar, atomic_short, atomic_ushort, atomic_int, 
                atomic_uint, atomic_long, atomic_ulong, atomic_llong, atomic_ullong, 
                virtual, PROGMEM,
                Serial, Serial1, Serial2, Serial3, SerialUSB, Keyboard, Mouse,
                abs, acos, asin, atan, atan2, ceil, constrain, cos, degrees, exp, 
                floor, log, map, max, min, radians, random, randomSeed, round, sin, 
                sq, sqrt, tan, pow, bitRead, bitWrite, bitSet, bitClear, bit, 
                highByte, lowByte, analogReference, analogRead, 
                analogReadResolution, analogWrite, analogWriteResolution, 
                attachInterrupt, detachInterrupt, digitalPinToInterrupt, delay, 
                delayMicroseconds, digitalWrite, digitalRead, interrupts, millis, 
                micros, noInterrupts, noTone, pinMode, pulseIn, pulseInLong, shiftIn, 
                shiftOut, tone, yield, Stream, begin, end, peek, read, print, 
                println, available, availableForWrite, flush, setTimeout, find, 
                findUntil, parseInt, parseFloat, readBytes, readBytesUntil, readString, 
                readStringUntil, trim, toUpperCase, toLowerCase, charAt, compareTo, 
                concat, endsWith, startsWith, equals, equalsIgnoreCase, getBytes, 
                indexOf, lastIndexOf, length, replace, setCharAt, substring, 
                toCharArray, toInt, press, release, releaseAll, accept, click, move, 
                isPressed, isAlphaNumeric, isAlpha, isAscii, isWhitespace, isControl, 
                isDigit, isGraph, isLowerCase, isPrintable, isPunct, isSpace, 
                isUpperCase, isHexadecimalDigit, 
                }, 
  morekeywords={   % add arduino structures to group 1
                break, case, override, final, continue, default, do, else, for, 
                if, return, goto, switch, throw, try, while, setup, loop, export, 
                not, or, and, xor, include, define, elif, else, error, if, ifdef, 
                ifndef, pragma, warning,
                }, 
% 
%
  %%% Keyword Color Group 2 %%%  (called LITERAL1 by arduino)
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{arduinoBlue},   
  keywords=[2]{   % add variables and dataTypes as 2nd group  
                HIGH, LOW, INPUT, INPUT_PULLUP, OUTPUT, DEC, BIN, HEX, OCT, PI, 
                HALF_PI, TWO_PI, LSBFIRST, MSBFIRST, CHANGE, FALLING, RISING, 
                DEFAULT, EXTERNAL, INTERNAL, INTERNAL1V1, INTERNAL2V56, LED_BUILTIN, 
                LED_BUILTIN_RX, LED_BUILTIN_TX, DIGITAL_MESSAGE, FIRMATA_STRING, 
                ANALOG_MESSAGE, REPORT_DIGITAL, REPORT_ANALOG, SET_PIN_MODE, 
                SYSTEM_RESET, SYSEX_START, auto, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, 
                uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, char16_t, char32_t, operator, 
                enum, delete, bool, boolean, byte, char, const, false, float, double, 
                null, NULL, int, long, new, private, protected, public, short, 
                signed, static, volatile, String, void, true, unsigned, word, array, 
                sizeof, dynamic_cast, typedef, const_cast, struct, static_cast, union, 
                friend, extern, class, reinterpret_cast, register, explicit, inline, 
                _Bool, complex, _Complex, _Imaginary, atomic_bool, atomic_char, 
                atomic_schar, atomic_uchar, atomic_short, atomic_ushort, atomic_int, 
                atomic_uint, atomic_long, atomic_ulong, atomic_llong, atomic_ullong, 
                virtual, PROGMEM,
                },  
% 
%
  %%% Keyword Color Group 3 %%%  (called KEYWORD1 by arduino)
  keywordstyle=[3]\bfseries\color{arduinoOrange},
  keywords=[3]{  % add built-in functions as a 3rd group
                Serial, Serial1, Serial2, Serial3, SerialUSB, Keyboard, Mouse,
                },      
%
%
  %%% Keyword Color Group 4 %%%  (called KEYWORD2 by arduino)
  keywordstyle=[4]\color{arduinoOrange},
  keywords=[4]{  % add more built-in functions as a 4th group
                abs, acos, asin, atan, atan2, ceil, constrain, cos, degrees, exp, 
                floor, log, map, max, min, radians, random, randomSeed, round, sin, 
                sq, sqrt, tan, pow, bitRead, bitWrite, bitSet, bitClear, bit, 
                highByte, lowByte, analogReference, analogRead, 
                analogReadResolution, analogWrite, analogWriteResolution, 
                attachInterrupt, detachInterrupt, digitalPinToInterrupt, delay, 
                delayMicroseconds, digitalWrite, digitalRead, interrupts, millis, 
                micros, noInterrupts, noTone, pinMode, pulseIn, pulseInLong, shiftIn, 
                shiftOut, tone, yield, Stream, begin, end, peek, read, print, 
                println, available, availableForWrite, flush, setTimeout, find, 
                findUntil, parseInt, parseFloat, readBytes, readBytesUntil, readString, 
                readStringUntil, trim, toUpperCase, toLowerCase, charAt, compareTo, 
                concat, endsWith, startsWith, equals, equalsIgnoreCase, getBytes, 
                indexOf, lastIndexOf, length, replace, setCharAt, substring, 
                toCharArray, toInt, press, release, releaseAll, accept, click, move, 
                isPressed, isAlphaNumeric, isAlpha, isAscii, isWhitespace, isControl, 
                isDigit, isGraph, isLowerCase, isPrintable, isPunct, isSpace, 
                isUpperCase, isHexadecimalDigit, 
                },      
%
%
  %%% Set Other Colors %%%
  stringstyle=\color{arduinoDarkBlue},    
  commentstyle=\color{arduinoGrey},    
%          
%   
  %%%% Line Numbering %%%%
   numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\color{arduinoGrey},    
  %stepnumber=2,                      % show every 2 line numbers
%
%
  %%%% Code Box Style %%%%
  breaklines=true,                    % wordwrapping
  tabsize=2,         
  basicstyle=\ttfamily  
}
```