# How to syntax-highlight an own language / unpopular language?

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting

How can I syntax-highlight an unpopular language that is not supported for lstlisting?

The language is called "Cypher" (for the graph database Neo4j) und I would like to highlight words like "RETURN", "MATCH" or Strings...

I there an easy way to so that?

Comment: Look at the documentation of package listings. There is a section about just that.

Comment: There is an example of a custom language at [How to set up listings for use code from Arduino?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211415/4301).

Answer (score 1):

The Cypher already has language has a lexer defined in pygments

http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.graph.CypherLexer

So it should work with the `minted` package which uses pygments to do the language-specific highlighting.