# Typesetting source code with listing package in Example environment

Tags: listings

I would like to use simple example environment with [listing](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) package for printing C-code snippets, like this

```
\begin{example}
   \lstinputlisting[caption=Hello.c]{../C/hello.c}
\end{example}
```

This works well with the exception of the selected font. I use

```
  \lstset{basicstyle=footnotesize\ttfamily}.
```

but, as you can see on the figure below, which does not match with selected shape. It seems that font shape selected for example environment has higher priority. **How can I properly set font shape for code snippet in the example environment, that match with \lstset command.**

[image]

Note: I use czech language: Příklad = Example

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{listings}
\newtheorem{example}{Příklad}

\begin{document}

\lstset{ %
  language=C,                            % choose the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
}

    \begin{example} 
      text text text 
      \begin{lstlisting}
        #include <stdio.h>

        int main(void)
        {
         int c;

         while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
           putchar(c);
         return 0;
        }
      \end{lstlisting}

    \end{example}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193475/87876) answer might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `example` environment from the `amsthm` package typesets the contents in italics. Internally, this is probably be done by calling `\itshape` at the beginning of the example. Now, when you create your listing, the style options `\footnotesize\ttfamily` are added, but the `\itshape` is still "active". For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    test \itshape test \ttfamily test \upshape test
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output of example]

The same happens in your example: The surrounding text is in `\itshape`, thus adding `\ttfamily` creates text in your *italic* typewriter font. To get upright typewriter font, you have to add `\upshape` to your listings style, as demonstrated in the example above.

Thus, your MWE becomes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{listings}
\newtheorem{example}{Příklad}

\begin{document}

\lstset{ %
  language=C,                                    % choose the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\upshape\ttfamily,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
}

    \begin{example} 
      text text text
      \begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
    return 0;
  }
      \end{lstlisting}
      text text text
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

and results in a listing as you would expect, with an upright typewriter font:

[image: result for the op's complete example]